# How to do r square for glmmTMB negative binomial mixed model with zero-inflation in r

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, variance, model-fitting

I made a zero-inflated negative binomial model with glmTMB as below

```
M2<- glmmTMB(psychological100~ (1|ID) + time*MNM01, data=mnmlong,
                      ziformula=~ (1|ID) + time*MNM01, family=nbinom2())

summary(M2)
```

Here is the output

```
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          psychological100 ~ (1 | ID) + time * MNM01
Zero inflation:                    ~(1 | ID) + time * MNM01
Data: mnmlong



AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  3507.0   3557.5  -1742.5   3485.0      714 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 0.2862   0.535   
Number of obs: 725, groups:  ID, 337

Zero-inflation model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 0.5403   0.7351  
Number of obs: 725, groups:  ID, 337

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 3.14 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.89772    0.09213  31.451  < 2e-16 ***
time        -0.08724    0.01796  -4.858 1.18e-06 ***
MNM01        0.02094    0.12433   0.168    0.866    
time:MNM01  -0.01193    0.02420  -0.493    0.622    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.29940    0.17298  -1.731 0.083478 .  
time         0.12204    0.03338   3.656 0.000256 ***
MNM01        0.06771    0.24217   0.280 0.779790    
time:MNM01  -0.02821    0.04462  -0.632 0.527282    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I wanted to know the R square of the model and tried the following 2 methods but not successful

```
MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM(M2)
```

> Error in r.squaredGLMM.glmmTMB(M2) :    r.squaredGLMM cannot (yet)
>   handle 'glmmTMB' object with zero-inflation

```
performance::r2_zeroinflated(M2)
```

> Error in residuals.glmmTMB(model, type = "pearson") :    pearson
>   residuals are not implemented for models with zero-inflation or
>   variable dispersion

what do you advise me?

Comment: I think it is quite complicated. Have you tried `r2_nakagawa()`? But I would read up on what it means first. Try https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x%4010.1111/%28ISSN%292041-210X.STATSTOO and https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949655.2016.1186166?journalCode=gscs20

Comment: As Dylan suggests, `performance::r2_nakagawa()` (or simply `performance::r2()`) should work.

Comment: These model are derived via maximum likelihood and rsquare simply doesn't exist for them. you can try something like a pseudo r squared but be careful about its interpretation. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/

Answer (score 0):

Try with the pseudo-R^2 based on a likelihood-ratio (`MuMIn::r.squaredLR`). You may need to provide a null model for comparison explicitly.